# Clearing Application Even Logs of specific application

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, batch-file

Is it possible to clear event logs of specific application (specific "Source" in Windows Event Log Viewer) via batch file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is unfortunately not possible since it would negatively affect the integrity of the log - mostly an issue with the security log. You can only clear the entire log.